# Installing CCR.EXIF Package in lazarus

Tags: delphi, gps, lazarus

I have installed the package CCR.EXIF which I found [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/lazarus-ccr/svn/HEAD/tree/components/fpexif/tests/unittest/common/fetexifle.pas#l59). But I have some issues with it.

I found the Code for reading GPS Information About a Image and I tried to use that Code but I get Errors on `CheckTrue` and now I'm not sure if thats a other programing language or if I made a installing mistake.

```
procedure TstExifLE.ReadGPSTest;

var
imgInfo: TImgInfo;
lTag: TTag;
begin
  imgInfo := TImgInfo.Create;
  try
imgInfo.LoadFromFile(WorkFile_JpegWithExif);

lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSVersionID'];
CheckTrue(lTag <> nil, 'Tag "GPSVersionID" not found');
CheckTrue(lTag is TVersionTag, 'Tag "GPSVersionID" is not TVersionTag');
TVersionTag(lTag).Separator := '.';
CheckEquals('2.3.0.0', lTag.AsString, 'Value mismatch of tag "GPSVersionID"');

lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLatitude'];
CheckTrue(lTag <> nil, 'Tag "GPSLatitude" not found');
CheckTrue(lTag is TGPSPositionTag, 'Tag "GPSLatitude" is not a TGpsPositionTag');
TGpsPositionTag(lTag).FormatStr := '%0:.0f deg %1:.0f'' %2:.2f"';
CheckEquals('51 deg 33'' 48.28"', lTag.AsString, 'Value mismatch of tag "GPSLatitude"');

lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLatitudeRef'];
CheckTrue(lTag <> nil, 'Tag "GPSLatitudeRef" not found');
CheckEquals('South', lTag.AsString, 'Value mismatch of tag "GPSLatitudeRef"');

lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLongitude'];
CheckTrue(lTag <> nil, 'Tag "GPSLongitude" not found');
CheckTrue(lTag is TGPSPositionTag, 'Tag "GPSLongitude" is not a TGpsPositionTag');
TGpsPositionTag(lTag).FormatStr := '%0:.0f deg %1:.0f'' %2:.2f"';
CheckEquals('59 deg 49'' 53.55"', lTag.AsString, 'Value mismatch of tag "GPSLongitude"');

lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLongitudeRef'];
CheckTrue(lTag <> nil, 'Tag "GPSLongitudeRef" not found');
CheckEquals('West', lTag.AsString, 'Value mismatch of tag "GPSLongitudeRef"');

finally
imgInfo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Error Message:

> -Identifier not found 'TstExifLE'
>
> -Identifier not found 'CheckTrue'
>
> -Identifier not found 'CheckEquals'

**Edit**
I made the class TstExifLe and that is the following error I get

> Identifier not found 'TTestCase'

Comment: Please show the code, causing problems, in its context. What error EXACTLY (use copy - paste to get the full error message.

Comment: The code you show seems to be a test in a test suit. It is certainly not code that you would want to use in your own project.

Comment: So instead of the CheckTrue and so on I simply have to make if's

Comment: No you are now in in the **unit tests** part of the package. I don't know the package but you should probably use code in the `fpexif` directory

Comment: WOW at the begining I was in this Folder but that someone showed me that example in the test and I got stuck. But my Problem now is that in the examples Folder there is no example for reading the GPS cooridinates. Package is in the Question as a link

Comment: But there was a link to another SO post in your previous (now deleted) post which showed you how. Are you able to compile that code in your own project?

Comment: Now that you have sorted out the issue with `CheckTru`()` you should post a new question regarding using the CCR.EXIF code for your purposes.

Comment: Yes i will but i have to wait because I can only post a Question every 90 minutes

Comment: Maybe you could upvote my Question? Because it says my last Questions were not accepted that good by the community and I could get a ban if I ask one more "bad" question

Comment: Since you follwed my request to add code and exact error message: +1

Comment: I have to thank you! Without you i wouldn't have solved this: +1 :)

Comment: BTW, the package linked to in the first post, is not CCR.EXIF, but fpexif, an independently written EXIF/IPTC library for Lazarus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have found is part of a DUnit test.  All DUnit tests descend from TTestCase and use methods CheckTrue, CheckEquals etc as assertions that the test has passed.  You will need to re-factor the code to eliminate the need for DUnit in order to compile it, or if you just want to see it in action download and install DUnit.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, this is how I would extract the GPS information:

```
  procedure TForm1.ReadGPS;
  var
    imgInfo: TImgInfo;
    lTag: TTag;
  begin
    imgInfo := TImgInfo.Create;
    try 
      imgInfo.LoadFromFile(WorkFile_JpegWithExif);

      lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSVersionID'];
      Memo1.Lines.Add('GPSVersionID: ' + lTag.AsString);

      lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLatitude'];
      TGpsPositionTag(lTag).FormatStr := '%0:.0f deg %1:.0f'' %2:.2f"';        
      Memo1.Lines.Add('GPSLatitude: ' + lTag.AsString);

      lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLatitudeRef'];
      Memo1.Lines.Add('GPSLatitudeRef: ' + lTag.AsString);

      lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLongitude'];
      TGpsPositionTag(lTag).FormatStr := '%0:.0f deg %1:.0f'' %2:.2f"';
      Memo1.Lines.Add('GPSLongitude: ' + lTag.AsString);

      lTag := imgInfo.ExifData.TagByName['GPSLongitudeRef'];
      Memo1.Lines.Add('GPSLongitudeRef: ' + lTag.AsString);

    finally
      imgInfo.Free;
    end;
  end;
```